# How can I use higher order functions like Array.reduce() in an Indesign script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I've started a project where I need to use Adobe Indesign and ExtendScript to programmatically extract some data from a series of INDD files. The version of Javascript used for scripting in these programs doesn't support any of the higher order functions that I'm used to using (`Array.reduce()`, `Array.forEach()`, `Array.map()`, etc...).

Is there a way to add this functionality to ExtendScript? I feel like I'm walking around in a room with a four foot high ceiling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use a Polyfill

ExtendScript appears to support prototyping of pure Javascript objects (but [not Indesign DOM objects](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/885254?tstart=0)), so it is possible to use a polyfill to add missing functionality. Polyfill code can be found on MDN on the page for the method in question under "Polyfill". Here's an example: [MDN Array.prototype.reduce() Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill). There are polyfills for numerous methods, including `Array.map()`, `Array.indexOf()`, `Array.filter()`, and `Array.forEach()`.

To implement the code, just create an appropriately named file (ie, `polyfill.js` or `reduce.js`) in the same folder as your script. Copy the polyfill code from MDN into the file you just created, like so:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.21
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.21
if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {
  Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback /*, initialValue*/) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.reduce called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }
    var t = Object(this), len = t.length >>> 0, k = 0, value;
    if (arguments.length == 2) {
      value = arguments[1];
    } else {
      while (k < len && !(k in t)) {
        k++; 
      }
      if (k >= len) {
        throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty array with no initial value');
      }
      value = t[k++];
    }
    for (; k < len; k++) {
      if (k in t) {
        value = callback(value, t[k], k, t);
      }
    }
    return value;
  };
}
```

Then add the following line at the beginning of your script, replacing the filename appropriately:

```
#include 'polyfill.js';
```

The semicolon at the end of the line isn't included in Adobe documentation, but I find that sometimes ExtendScript throws an error if it's left off, especially if you're using `#include` multiple times.

Comment: It would be helpful to share your polyfill.js on github for others with the same problem.

Comment: @georg I'm doing that here https://github.com/fabiantheblind/extendscript.prototypes contributions are welcome

Answer (score 3):

I use underscore.js instead.

Underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/

```
#include '/path-to/underscore.js'
var _ = this._;
```

adding this snippet at the beginning of the script.

thank you

mg.